# WPF GridView sorting when clicking column header

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listview, gridview

I am implementing a GridView which sorts by clicking on the column headers. I was finding one of the standard solutions, but it did not work for me.

I have a header "P" while both the content of the cells and the header should centered (alignment). The header has a different label "P" than the binding "Photo".

```
<GridViewColumn Width="30" Header="P">

    <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>

        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Photo}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

</GridViewColumn>
```

The code that handels the column click is as follows below (from the Mircosoft site).

It assumes that there is a DisplayMemberBinding

```cs
var columnBinding = headerClicked.Column.DisplayMemberBinding as Binding;
```

Which I do not have, otherwise the column header and content is not centered.

Otherwise it takes the label of the column as property for sorting.

```cs
var sortBy = columnBinding?.Path.Path ?? headerClicked.Column.Header as string;
```

This does not work either because my label is "P" and the property is "Photo".

Any other idea?

```
internal void HandleOverviewColumnHeaderClicked(GridViewColumnHeader headerClicked)
{
    ListSortDirection direction;

    if (headerClicked != null)
    {
        if (headerClicked.Role != GridViewColumnHeaderRole.Padding)
        {
            if (headerClicked != _lastHeaderClicked)
            {
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_lastDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                }
            }

            var columnBinding = headerClicked.Column.DisplayMemberBinding as Binding;
            var sortBy = columnBinding?.Path.Path ?? headerClicked.Column.Header as string;

            Sort(sortBy, direction);

            if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                headerClicked.Column.HeaderTemplate = _window.Resources["HeaderTemplateArrowUp"] as DataTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                headerClicked.Column.HeaderTemplate = _window.Resources["HeaderTemplateArrowDown"] as DataTemplate;
            }

            // Remove arrow from previously sorted header
            if (_lastHeaderClicked != null && _lastHeaderClicked != headerClicked)
            {
                _lastHeaderClicked.Column.HeaderTemplate = null;
            }

            _lastHeaderClicked = headerClicked;
            _lastDirection = direction; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MyData}">
      <GridViewColumnHeader Content="MyHeader" Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click" />
</GridViewColumn>
```

and

```
        GridViewColumnHeader _lastHeaderClicked = null;
        ListSortDirection _lastDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;

        private void GridViewColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            var headerClicked = e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader;
            ListSortDirection direction;

            if (headerClicked != null)
            {
                if (headerClicked.Role != GridViewColumnHeaderRole.Padding)
                {
                    if (headerClicked != _lastHeaderClicked)
                    {
                        direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (_lastDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                        {
                            direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                        }
                    }

                    var columnBinding = headerClicked.Column.DisplayMemberBinding as Binding;
                    var sortBy = columnBinding?.Path.Path ?? headerClicked.Column.Header as string;

                    Sort(sortBy, direction);

                    if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        headerClicked.Column.HeaderTemplate =
                          Resources["HeaderTemplateArrowUp"] as DataTemplate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        headerClicked.Column.HeaderTemplate =
                          Resources["HeaderTemplateArrowDown"] as DataTemplate;
                    }

                    // Remove arrow from previously sorted header
                    if (_lastHeaderClicked != null && _lastHeaderClicked != headerClicked)
                    {
                        _lastHeaderClicked.Column.HeaderTemplate = null;
                    }

                    _lastHeaderClicked = headerClicked;
                    _lastDirection = direction;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Sort(string sortBy, ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            ICollectionView dataView =
              CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lv.ItemsSource);

            dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            SortDescription sd = new SortDescription(sortBy, direction);
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
            dataView.Refresh();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Tag property to set the data member to sort by, since the DisplayMemberBinding and Header don't contain the name you need.  Then get the Tag similar to the way your sample code is accessing the DisplayMemberBinding.